# Why do some Twitch channels have one time subscription fees?

Tags: twitch.tv

Why do some channels such as [Jesse Cox](https://www.twitch.tv/jessecox), [Vlambeer](https://www.twitch.tv/vlambeer), and [Felicia Day](https://www.twitch.tv/feliciaday) offer one time subscriptions instead of monthly sub fees?

Aren't Twitch subscriptions supposed to cost $4.99 per month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When subscription buttons were first added, Twitch experimented by offering non-standard sub-options such as $2.99 subs and one-time subscriptions.

While Twitch no longer offers one-time sub fees, partner channels that signed up were allowed to continue offering one-time subscriptions.

It's worth noting that [Twitch Prime subscriptions ***can*** be used for channels with one-time sub fees.](https://twitter.com/JesseCox/status/795703163063922688)

You can still request a one time subscription for your channel by either requesting it through Emmett Shear personal twitch channel or requesting it directly to another high ranking twitch employee but you must have proven yourself to be a dedicated active streamer on the website with a large sized following. Your not guaranteed to acquire it as it's a feature the staff does not like to grant users since it hurts their profits but unless you ask for it they won't give it to you.

---

**List of channels with one-time subscriptions:**

- [Evo](https://www.twitch.tv/evo) (*Previously srkevo1*) - $12.00 / One Time
- [FeliciaDay](https://www.twitch.tv/feliciaday) - $4.99 / One Time
- [RyonDay](https://www.twitch.tv/ryonday) - $4.99 / One Time
- [JesseCox](https://www.twitch.tv/JesseCox) (*Previously shaboozey*) - $2.99 / One Time
- [Vlambeer](https://www.twitch.tv/vlambeer) - $12.99 / One Time